# What is the totient function for an RSA modulus has several factors due to incorrect setup?

Tags: rsa

$ϕ(n)=p.q−(p+q)+1$ where there are two factor $p$ and $q$, but what if there were 3 (or more) factors such as $(p,q,r)$ due to a typo in specifying the modulus?

Comment: In RSA, both $n$ and $\phi(n)$ are computed from $p$ and $q$ (and possibly additional primes). $\phi(n)$ is not computed from $n$: if that was possible, $n$ would be insecure. Possible or not, if there's a typo in typing $n$, it becomes unusable, and there's no point in trying to compute a new $\phi(n)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\phi(p \cdot q \cdot r \cdot ... \cdot s) = (p-1)(q-1)(r-1)...(s-1)$ (for $p, q, r, ..., s$ distinct primes)

In addition, the technically correct modulus for which $e \cdot d \equiv 1$ must hold is commonly known as $\lambda(n)$; in this case,

$\lambda(p \cdot q \cdot r \cdot ... \cdot s) = \text{lcm}(p-1, q-1, r-1, ..., s-1)$

Comment: $\lambda$ is known as *Carmichael's function*.  Namely, $\lambda(N)$ represents the exponent of the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$.

Comment: If $\phi(N)$ denotes the order of $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$, it can be observed that $\lambda(N)$ divides $\phi(N)$.